# half of the jQuery scripts of my webpage not launching on raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, jquery, raspberry-pi

I've made a website that works perfectly fine on computers but I've tried porting it to raspberry pi and for some reason only half of the scripts work

[here's the website](http://googledrive.com/host/0ByBwY60ZsbQpZjFJaDhTQlRfdTg/)

when porting it to raspberry pi, I cannot see the analyzer in the background, I cannot open the menu on the right, the timeline on the media player doesn't update and I cannot hide it

does anybody know why it's doing that?

Comment: There are problems with the linking of the files..

I have it also on Firefox, in console Firebug I see networkerrors (css, jquery, images,...)

Comment: I don't see those errors in the console

Comment: Maybe there are problems with the rights for the documents on the google drive?

I have probably no rights, so it doesn't load.. You have the correct rights,...

Thats probably the problem on the rasperry pi.

Comment: I'm not using the google drive version, I've copied all the local files

Answer (score 1):

I added a screenshot with the errors.

You uses google drive as host (the link you posted). You have to check the permissions. If you don't know how, take a look on the [Drive Help, hosting webpages](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)

EDIT:
The permissions are ok. But I found the problem:
You have to change linking of the files that you want to load:

```
<script src="Scripts\jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
<script src="Scripts\jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom\jquery-ui.js">
<link href="Scripts\jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom\jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="Scripts\jquery.textfill.min.js">
<script src="Scripts\Options.js">
<script src="Scripts\DVR button Press functions.js">
```

to

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js">
<link href="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="Scripts/jquery.textfill.min.js">
<script src="Scripts/Options.js">
<script src="Scripts/DVR button Press functions.js">
```

[image: Errors]

Comment: I also have this problem on the google drive version (only on mozilla), but it works fine when I open it locally

Comment: also, every single file is set as public already, I've just checked

Comment: I looked deeper in the source..

Can you do absolute url to the public files as a test?

<script src="Scripts\jquery-1.11.2.min.js"> returns a 404,...

Comment: absolute url? what do you mean?

Comment: Edited my answer. I found the solution :)

Comment: yup, that fixed it! why was that such a big problem for mozilla?

Comment: Firefox changes it to html code %5C

Is the problem solved with the Rasperry Pi as well?

Comment: I don't know, I use it in my school, so I'll have to test tomorrow :/

Comment: I've just tested it on the raspberry pi, still not fixed

Comment: Is it the same problem?

Comment: I've figured out half of the problem, the only script that isn't working is the one using the web audio API, is it on the raspberry pi?

Comment: i'm not familiar with audio on raspberry pie, but maybe this tutorial can help: http://nmecdesign.com/blog/audio-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-node-js/

Comment: basically, I have a visualizer and I want to make it work on it, but node.js doesn't seem to allow that